# unable to install gem pg - Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

In ubuntu 14.04 I can't install `pg` gem, however I installed the libpg-dev as well.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

[Here](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-chef/issues/270) I can see some other people have the same issue.

```
gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141202-24533-1xrmav0.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
```

any help?

Comment: strange problem...i don't know, but try ruby `sudo ldconfig`, then try again

Comment: Yeah, its still the same.

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -S  /usr/lib/libpq.so`?

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/lib/libpq.so` returns 
`libpq-dev: /usr/lib/libpq.so`

Comment: could you do `sudo grep PQconnectdb /usr/lib/libpq.so`?

Answer (score 4):

Run this code `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.18.2'` then `bundle install`. It should install the pg gem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should post online your `mkmf.log` file, but you also need to check if your Ruby and PostgreSQL are using the same OpenSSL version.

It could happen that you've installed Ruby and OpenSSL by RVM and your PostgreSQL is using the system's version. This will lead to conflict.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had installed OpenSSL via linuxbrew and apt-get.  Deleted my brew version and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have Postgres installed correctly. Did you try to pass the archflags like this?

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that; its not working.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue on my PC. I just run `rvm get stable` for updating `rvm` and run one more time `bundle install`. After this pg gem was installed successfully.

Comment: still the same `rvm -v` : 
`rvm 1.26.3 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`